# How can I exclude a source property while mapping automatically with Automapper in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In C#, supposing that I have a Class A that looks like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}
```

And a Class B:

```
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public Guid ExtraProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and finally a Class C:

```
public class ClassC
{
    public ClassA classA { get; set; }
    public Guid ExtraProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How can I map ClassB automatically to ClassC using Automapper without getting an error? Before this ExtraProperty was added in ClassB and ClassC it was as simple as writing:

```
CreateMap<ClassB, ClassC>()
            .ForMember(c=> c.classA, o => o.MapFrom(b => b));
```

But now this throws an exception showing:

```
Expectation has property root.ExtraProperty that the other object does not have.
```

I don't mind mapping the ExtraProperty manually but it's important that the other properties can be mapped automatically, I've tried using Ignore() on it and DoNotValidate() for the source member but no results, any help? Thanks!

Comment: *Expectation has property root.ExtraProperty that the other object does not have.* this exception message is thrown by AutoMapper? If not, please show the code that throw this exception.

Answer (score 4):

> Expectation has property root.ExtraProperty that the other object does not have.

This is not an AutoMapper error (which works correctly and maps the property), this seems to come from [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/), so you need to fix the test (validate that you are mapping from correct object and/or validate from correct one). For example the following will result in the aforementioned error:

```cs
var classB = new ClassB
{
    ExtraProperty = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Entity = "asas"
};

new ClassA
    {
        Entity = classB.Entity
    }
    .Should()
    .BeEquivalentTo(classB);
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I thought this was coming from Automapper but it actually does map correctly